# Hidden services on bootable external HDD

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, ubuntu

Can one run hidden services from bootable external HDD?

I would like to install ubuntu, nginx, php, TBB on external HDD and boot the HDD when starting... seems like this should work just fine. Have anyone else tried this configuration?

Comment: Many thanks to Kelby and his vid tutorial on installing ubuntu to ext hdd. [YouTube tute from Kelby][1]. Now onto building out the hidden service. I'll keep posting updates here until successful. Gracias


  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDM2LqFoHv4

Answer (score 1):

As long as everything is configured correctly it should work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

STOP!

Ubuntu is not a distribution built for security, if you want to use a Linux host, use [Debian](http://debian.org). TorProject itself recommends [thttpd](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/) for webservers.

Comment: Thanks dude. so can thtpd run php? can you recommend a debian version?

Comment: thttpd can run php, as for debian version, I recommend wheezy(currentstable). If you really want full on security, take a look Whonix (https://whonix.org)

Comment: how to install whonix on an external hdd? It does not come as an ISO so cant burn to dvd.

Comment: Help! Spending hours trying to understand basics. I installed debian on external with default web server. Then I installed lighttpd which failed to connect to port 80. I stopped apache and restarted lighttpd. Cannot get any webpages to render at localhost. this is so simple with wamp or lemp why cant i see my index page using this webserver?